# Flip Flop Circuit that has two inputs?

Tags: components, circuit-design, identification

For a project that I am working on, I need a circuit that can take a momentary pulse of voltage and then output a constant voltage until the other input is triggered. Kind of like a flip flop but with two inputs: [image: component_x]

So when a voltage is applied to A, P will output a voltage until B has a voltage applied to it.

Does such a circuit exist and if so, what is it called?

Thank You!

Comment: This one is called "SR-Latch" (set-reset-latch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Turbo J said, the device performing that function is a SR latch. The [CD4043 and CD4044](https://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/cd40/cd4043bms-44bms.pdf) ICs may be what you're looking for. Then you'll have to add an inverter in order to generate the Q output. You can use the [74HC04](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls04.pdf) inverter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO7BMw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

OTOH, if you need your P, Q voltages to be different from the A, B peak voltages then you'll have to implement some kind of logic level conversion. A simple transistor switch will do the trick. Even better, you can save the 74HC04 inverters by using complementary transistors for the switches.

There is also a synchronous version of the SR latch: the [JK flip-flop](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/sequential/seq_2.html). But it may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: Why suggest mixing cmos and ttl (with the possibility of having to change voltage levels) when there are plenty of cmos chips that could provide an inverter? Besides a 4001 (quad 2 input NOR) would do it all in one chip. The 4044 is a **not set**, **not reset** type latch.

Comment: Because the OP speaks of "voltages" instead of "logic levels". note that in my first unedited answer I also suggest to use an inverter. Also, I don't suggest specifically the 4044 IC, as the OP also don't specifies the input voltage polarity.

Comment: Thank you! This is ideal. Thank you for providing links as well

Answer (score 1):

"a circuit that can take a momentary pulse of voltage and then output a constant voltage until the other input is triggered"

The basic latch is an S-R type (set, reset). To allow it to operate with a pulse then we can use one of the edges of the input signal. I've chosen the positive edge. By adding a simple circuit (edge detector) before the latch we can operate the latch with pulses.

[image]

The pulse produced is very short (= propagation delay of one not gate). If the pulse needs to be longer simply add more gates (odd numbers).

*Note that the circuit only produces a pulse on the positive edge and not the falling edge.*

The SR flip flop can be easily made using two gates from a single 4001 CMOS chip.

[image]

*Why bother adding the pulse edge detector?*

An S-R flip flop works fine **when only one of the inputs is high**. When both inputs are high that's when the problems start. By triggering the change on the input pulse edge rather than the pulse level you avoid this indeterminate situation.